# How to implement push notifications using firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I´m trying to implement push notifications in a chat using firebase cloud functions.

My database does look something like this:

- messages

  - messageId

    - fromId: ""
    - toId: ""
    - messageText: ""
- users

  - userId

    - username: "Frank"
    - fcmToken: "odnue38dh93hjd903jdn3obd3jfb393f"

My functions code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.observeChat = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate((snaphot, context) => {

  var messageId = context.params.messageId;

  return admin.database().ref('/messages/' + messageId).once('value', snapshot => {
    var newMessage = snapshot.val();
    var toUid = newMessage.toId;

    console.log('LOGGER -> toid  ' + toUid);

      return admin.database().ref('/users/' + toUid).once('value', snaphsot => {
        var userTextedTo = snapshot.val();

        console.log('LOGGER -> fcmtoken   ' + userTextedTo.fcmToken);
        console.log('LOGGER -> name ' + userTextedTo.username);

        var payload = {
            notification: {
              title: 'New Message',
              body: userTextedTo.username + 'did message you'
            }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTextedTo.fcmToken, payload)
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
          });
    })
  })
})
```

Firebase functions log

```
Function execution started


LOGGER -> toid YyUZ3ESFA2UHTlTFurqEvpRaspu2


Function execution took 708 ms, finished with status: 'ok'


LOGGER -> fcmtoken undefined


LOGGER -> name undefined 

@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.

Uncaught exception 

Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
```

So I guess there is something wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Log: `LOGGER -> Usertexted [object Object] with code console.log('LOGGER -> Usertexted ' + userTextedTo);`